# How can I make one function to close modals with different content in JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have three modals containing a video. Each button opens the same modal but it shows a different video depending on the buttom you clicked. It works fine, but I want to shut off the sound when closing the modal. There is a function to do that named closeVideo(), but it only works for the first modal, and not for the others.
Is there a way to create just one function to shut off the sound of every modal?

```
                    <div class="box">
                       <div class="piece">
                            <h2>Medcom</h2>
                            <div class="xbox">
                                <a class="ibutton trigger">
                                    <h3>Ver video</h3>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="box">
                        <div class="piece">
                            <h2>Juan Valdez</h2>
                            <div class="xbox">
                                <a class="ibutton trigger">
                                    <h3>Ver video</h3>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="box">
                        <div class="piece">
                            <h2>Grupo Epasa</h2>
                            <div class="xbox">
                                <a class="ibutton trigger">
                                    <h3>Ver video</h3>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

<div class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="btn-close" (click)='closeVideo()'>
        <img src="../../../../../assets/img/close.svg" alt="close">
    </span>
        <iframe id="player" width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/N8ABAZvh8WE" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="btn-close" (click)='closeVideo()'>
        <img src="../../../../../assets/img/close.svg" alt="close">
    </span>
        <iframe id="player" width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/rn937OyA00g" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="btn-close" (click)='closeVideo()'>
        <img src="../../../../../assets/img/close.svg" alt="close">
    </span>
        <iframe id="player" width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/EUjWFr3w7RU" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
    /*    SHOW MODALS   */
    const triggers = document.getElementsByClassName('trigger');
    const triggerArray = Array.from(triggers).entries();
    const modals = document.getElementsByClassName('modal');
    const closeButton = document.getElementsByClassName('btn-close');

    const myPlayer = document.getElementById('player');

    for (let [index, trigger] of triggerArray) {
      let triggerIndex = index;
      function toggleModal() {
        modals[triggerIndex].classList.toggle('show-modal');
      }
      trigger.addEventListener("click", toggleModal);
      closeButton[triggerIndex].addEventListener("click", toggleModal);
    }

  closeVideo(){
    myPlayer.setAttribute("src", " ");
    console.log('video is closed now!');
  }
```

Comment: You have multiple elements with the same `id`, therefore your HTML is invalid and this behaviour is entirely expected. Why not have one modal and, depending on the button that is clicked, load the relevant video into the one modal?

Comment: Hello, thanks for your advice, ot sounds the best solution. I will try to do so, since I am a little newbie. thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure what `(click)` is but the function assigned to `onClick` gets an event param. The event has a target that will indicate which button was pressed. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target

Comment: Can you share enough of your HTML that we can see your `<button>` elements as well? We need enough of your "*[mcve]*" code that we can reproduce your problem.

Comment: Hello David. I have uploaded my HTML. As I said before I just want one single function to close the modal as well of the sound of the video in it. The thing is that I made one modal per video. So that was a horrible approach, jaja!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that you're having trouble is due to the repetition of the `id` across all `<iframe>` elements; as any `id` can be used only *once* within an HTML document JavaScript will only ever look for precisely one element with a given `id`; hence in this case if it finds an element with `id="player"` it will not look for any other element with that `id` attribute-value, since none should exist.

One solution, therefore, is to change the `id` to a `class` and therefore JavaScript will look for *all* elements with that class-name, then you could iterate through those elements and hide all of them:

```
closeVideo(){
  let myPlayers = document.querySelectorAll('.player');

  // here we use NodeList.forEach() to iterate through the
  // NodeList returned by document.querySelectorAll(), and
  // use an Arrow function as the callback:
  myPlayers.forEach(
    // here 'player' is the current element of the NodeList
    // over which we're iterating; and we set the src of each
    // element of the NodeList in turn to an empty string:
    (player) => player.setAttribute('src','')
  );
  console.log('video is closed now!');
}
```

Of course this requires the HTML to be updated, to the following:

```
<div class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="btn-close" (click)='closeVideo()'>
        <img src="../../../../../assets/img/close.svg" alt="close">
    </span>
    <!-- note the change from id="player" to class="player"
         this is true of all elements, though for brevity I'm
         only showing one element -->
    <iframe class="player" width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/N8ABAZvh8WE" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  </div>
</div>
```

However, once this is done you still have three modal elements, each with a different video within it. It's important to remember that one of the general principle of  most programming is that of "DRY": Don't Repeat Yourself.

With that in mind, especially given the repetition of the elements themselves, it seems easier to use the `<button>` elements to pass in the relevant data, taking advantage of custom `data-*` attributes, such as:

```
<!-- here we use the data-video-id attribute to hold the video's id,
     the data-platform-base attribute to hold the relevant base-URL
     of the platform, and we use the videoPlayer function itself to
     create the relevant src: -->
<button data-video-id="N8ABAZvh8WE" data-platform-base="https://www.youtube.com/embed/">Open: </button>
```

```js
// here the event argument is passed in automatically by
// the later use of EventTarget.addEventListener(); we're using
// Arrow function syntax, since we have no need to use 'this'
// in the function:
const closeVideo = (event) => {

    // event.target is the element that originally triggered
    // the eventListener was listening for:
    let closeButton = event.target,
      // we use Element.closest() to find the first ancestor
      // element of the event.target that matches the supplied
      // CSS selector:
      modal = closeButton.closest('div.modal'),
      // from that modal element we use querySelector() to find
      // the first of any elements that match the supplied CSS
      // selector:
      player = modal.querySelector('iframe');


    // here we update the 'hidden' property of the modal element
    // to true in order to hide the element:
    modal.hidden = true;
    // we update - or rather remove - the player's src, by setting
    // that src to null (in order to stop the video and any sound
    // from playing):
    player.src = null;
  },

  // here we retrieve all the <button> elements that have a
  // data-video-id attribute and which have a data-platform-base
  // attribute:
  buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button[data-video-id][data-platform-base]'),
  // we find the modal element using document.querySelector() to search
  // the document for the first of any elements that match the supplied
  // CSS selector:
  modal = document.querySelector('div.modal');

// here we use querySelector() again to search within the modal
// element (the div.modal element found above) to find the first
// <span> element with the class of 'btn-close', and use
// EventTarget.addEventListener() to bind the closeVideo() function
// (note the deliberate lack of parentheses on the function name)
// as the event-handler for the 'click' event:
modal.querySelector('span.btn-close').addEventListener('click', closeVideo);

// we use NodeList.forEach() to iterate over the NodeList returned by
// document.querySelectorAll():
buttons.forEach(
  // using Arrow function syntax:
  // we again use EventTarget.addEventListener() to bind the
  // anonymous function as the event-handler for the 'click'
  // event:
  (button) => button.addEventListener('click', () => {

    // here we cache a reference to the button.dataset DOMStringMap
    // of custom data-* attributes and properties:
    const data = button.dataset,
      // here we create a url from the attribute-values held in the
      // data-platform-base and data-video-id properties (note that
      // these attribute-names are camel-cased as normal in JavaScript;
      // these properties are retrieved within the jQuery-like
      // ${...} and interpolated into the String:
      url = `${data.platformBase}${data.videoId}`,
      // we find the modal element:
      modal = document.querySelector('div.modal'),
      // we find the player element:
      player = modal.querySelector('iframe');

    // we update the src attribute of the player:
    player.src = url;
    // then we update the modal.hidden property to true, in order
    // to show that element:
    modal.hidden = false;
  })
);
```

```css
*,
 ::before,
 ::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}


/*
  here we position the modal element centred on the page,
  and with a low z-index to keep it below the page content:
*/

.modal {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  z-index: -1000;
}


/*
  here we update the z-index to a high number, in order to lift
  it above the page-content; the selector here selects:
  - all elements with a class of 'modal',
  - which do not have the hidden attribute, using the
    attribute-selector ([hidden]) within CSS' negation-operator
    ( :not() )
*/

.modal:not([hidden]) {
  z-index: 1000;
}


/*
  here we show the video id in the <button> elements:
*/

button::after {
  content: attr(data-video-id);
}

span.btn-close {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 2px solid #aaa;
  width: 3ex;
  height: 3ex;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 3ex;
}
```

```html
<!-- Note the addition of the 'hidden' attribute, below: -->
<div class="modal" hidden>
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="btn-close">X</span>
    <iframe id="player" width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/N8ABAZvh8WE" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  </div>
</div>

<button data-video-id="N8ABAZvh8WE" data-platform-base="https://www.youtube.com/embed/">Open: </button>
<button data-video-id="rn937OyA00g" data-platform-base="https://www.youtube.com/embed/">Open: </button>
<button data-video-id="EUjWFr3w7RU" data-platform-base="https://www.youtube.com/embed/">Open: </button>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/my5zsw48/1/).

> [In] case, I don't want to apply the 'DRY' concept and keep several modals in my HTML, Is there a way to use the `forEach()` function, and still be able to open and see the other videos? I mean, after iterating the elements with class 'player' ? because I have seen it makes all the remaining videos hidden. Just curious about it.

<sub>Comment from OP, below: [How can I make one function to close modals with different content in JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66429244/how-can-i-make-one-function-to-close-modals-with-different-content-in-js/66430595#comment117442492_66430595).</sub>

I'm not entirely sure that I understood the request on first reading, my first thoughts are below. This approach emulates the first approach (above), in that only one video/'modal' is visible at any one time. If I've misunderstood please clarify in the comments below and I'll attempt to improve the answer to meet your needs.

```js
// here we define a 'modals' Object that serves as a
// repository of functions and controls for the
// interactivity:
const modals = {
  // a 'buttons' Object that caches the relevant
  // control elements:
  buttons: {
    show: document.querySelectorAll('.trigger'),
    hide: document.querySelectorAll('.btn-close'),
  },

  // functions, which serve to provide the interactivity;
  // here we have an EventObject ('evt') passed to the
  // show() function (passed automatically by the later
  // use of EventTarget.addEventListener()):
  show: function(evt) {
    // EventObject.currentTarget returns the element to
    // which the event-listener was bound
    // (EventObject.target returns the element that
    // triggered the listened-for action, which may be
    // the element itself or a descendant of that element):
    let clicked = evt.currentTarget,

      // we retrieve the relevant index from the element's
      // dataset (we assign that value in later code) and
      // and cast it to an integer, with parseInt(), in
      // base-10 (hence the '10' as the second argument):
      i = parseInt(clicked.dataset.index, 10),

      // here we retrieve the elements with a class of
      // 'modal':
      modalBoxes = document.querySelectorAll('.modal');

    // iterating over those elements using
    // NodeList.prototype.forEach():
    modalBoxes.forEach(

      // we pass two arguments into the function, both
      // of which are available automatically; 'modal'
      // is a reference to the current Node of the
      // NodeList over which we're iterating, and 'index'
      // is the index of the current Node within the
      // NodeList itself.
      // in the function we're updating the modal.hidden
      // property, we want to show the modal if its index
      // matches; so if the i is not equal to index the
      // modal is hidden, otherwise the modal is shown by
      // as its index is equal to 'i' and therefore the
      // assessment is false, so hidden its hidden property
      // is false, therefore it's shown:
      (modal, index) => modal.hidden = i !== index
    );
  },
  hide: (evt) => {
    // here we're navigating from the element to which
    // the event-listener was bound up to the first
    // ancestor element with the class of 'modal':
    const m = evt.currentTarget.closest('.modal'),

          // from there we retrieve the <iframe> element:
          iframe = m.querySelector('iframe');

    // here we hide the modal:
    m.hidden = true;

    // here we update the src of the <iframe> to be equal
    // its own src; this causes a reload of the content
    // and as such stops it from playing:
    iframe.src = iframe.src;
  },

  // an initialisation function:
  init: function() {
    // here we're using destructuring to assign the
    // 'hide' and 'show' properties of the
    // this.buttons Object to variables of the same
    // name:
    const {
      show,
      hide
    } = this.buttons;

    // here we retrieve the NodeList of '.modal' elements
    // and then iterate over them:
    document.querySelectorAll('.modal').forEach(
      (modal) => {
        // we're initially hiding all '.modal' elements:
        modal.hidden = true;
      });

    // iterating over the 'show' elements:
    show.forEach(
      // passing in two arguments, 'btn' is the reference
      // to the current Node in the NodeList, and 'i' is
      // the current Node's index in that NodeList:
      (btn, i) => {

        // here we set the element's data-index attribute by
        // setting its dataset.index property to be equal to
        // the index of the current 'show' element:
        btn.dataset.index = i;

        // binding the function of the current modals Object
        // as the event-handling function of the 'click' event:
        btn.addEventListener('click', this.show);
      });

    // similar to the above, but binding the hide() function
    // of the modals Object as the event-handler for the
    // 'click' event on each of the 'hide' elements:
    hide.forEach(
      (btn) => {
        btn.addEventListener('click', this.hide);
      });
  },
};

// initialising the functionality:
modals.init();
```

```css
*,
 ::before,
 ::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

main {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.box {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <header>
    <div class="box">
      <div class="piece">
        <h2>Medcom</h2>
        <div class="box">
          <button class="ibutton trigger">
            <h3>Ver video</h3>
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <div class="piece">
        <h2>Juan Valdez</h2>
        <div class="xbox">
          <button class="ibutton trigger">
            <h3>Ver video</h3>
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <div class="piece">
        <h2>Grupo Epasa</h2>
        <div class="xbox">
          <button class="ibutton trigger">
            <h3>Ver video</h3>
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>

  <div class="videoContent">
    <div class="modal">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <span class="btn-close">
          <img src="../../../../../assets/img/close.svg" alt="close">
        </span>
        <iframe class="player" width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/N8ABAZvh8WE" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <span class="btn-close">
          <img src="../../../../../assets/img/close.svg" alt="close">
        </span>
        <iframe class="player" width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/rn937OyA00g" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="modal">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <span class="btn-close">
          <img src="../../../../../assets/img/close.svg" alt="close">
        </span>
        <iframe class="player" width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/EUjWFr3w7RU" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/my5zsw48/2/).

Reference:

- CSS:
- [Attribute selectors (`[attribute]`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors).
- [Negation (`:not()`) pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not).
- HTML:
- [`hidden`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/hidden).
- JavaScript:
- [Arrow function expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).
- [Destructuring assignment `{a,b} = ObjectName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).
- [`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector).
- [`Element.closest()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest).
- [`Element.setAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute).
- [`Event.currentTarget`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget)
- [`Event.target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target).
- [`EventTarget.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).
- [`HTMLElement.hidden`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/hidden).
- [`HTMLOrForeignElement.dataset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOrForeignElement/dataset).
- [`NodeList.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach).
- [Template literals (Template strings)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

Comment: That is absolutely amazing David! It is been very helpful comment, since I haven´t had the proper knowledge to do that. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Hello David, Just in case, I dont want to apply the 'DRY' concept and keep several modals in my HTML, Is there a way to use the forEach function, and still be able to open and see the other videos? I mean, after iterating the elements with class 'player' ? because I have seen it makes all the remaining videos hidden. Just curious about it.

Comment: So you'd want to show one video at a time, and hide the others? And still use the close button within each modal to hide the currently visible modal? Basically, sure: but it'll be tomorrow when I take a look now. Sorry, it just got a bit late in the UK.

Comment: Oh never mind, it was just for curiosity. We may talk later then. Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score -1):

you can perform the following function in JavaScript

```
$(function(){
  $('.modal').hide();
});
```

o

Save it in an array and then loop through that array and close one by one with adding the hide class

```
$(function(){
     var arrayModals=$('.modal');
     for(var modalObj:arrayModals){
        //do stuff here
        $(document.find(modalobj).getId()).toggleClass('visible');
     }
}):
```

only do it in the event you want either by clicking or detecting the end of a video

Comment: "*guardarlos en una variable y posteriormente recorrer esa variable y cerrar uno a uno*" - please remember that Stack Overflow is an English language website.